# Problems updating very simple appwidget

Tags: android, android-widget

I've been following [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf) tutorial trying to make a very simple clock widget for android. I'm able to create the widget, but it does not seem to update. I find this very strange as my code seems to be essentially what the same as [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html) at the android dev blog does.

When I add the widget to the home screen (Android 2.2 emulator) I get the following messages in logCat:

```
I/ActivityManager(   68): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_PICK cmp=com.android.settings/.AppWidgetPickActivity (has extras) }
W/InputManagerService(   68): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44fbaf40
I/AppWidgetPickActivity(  135): EXTRA_CUSTOM_INFO not present.
I/ActivityManager(   68): Displayed activity com.android.settings/.AppWidgetPickActivity: 1181 ms (total 1181 ms)
W/ActivityManager(   68): Unable to launch app com.levold.customClockWidget/10036 for broadcast Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED cmp=com.levold.customClockWidget/.ClockWidget }: process is bad
W/ActivityManager(   68): finishReceiver called but none active
W/ActivityManager(   68): Unable to launch app com.levold.customClockWidget/10036 for broadcast Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE cmp=com.levold.customClockWidget/.ClockWidget (has extras) }: process is bad
W/ActivityManager(   68): finishReceiver called but none active
W/InputManagerService(   68): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44fe1c50
```

The lines `Unable to launch app com.levold.customClockWidget/10036 for broadcast Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED cmp=com.levold.customClockWidget/.ClockWidget }: process is bad` seems to be the most relevant here, but I haven't been able to find much info about it.

Most of the code is below. If anybody could help that would be absolutely great, I'm pretty much stuck at the moment...

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.levold.customClockWidget"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
    <receiver android:name=".ClockWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/custom_clock_widget" />
    </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**xml/custom_clock_widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
/>
```

**src/com/levold/customClockWidget/ClockWidget.java**

```
package com.levold.customClockWidget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ClockWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Updating widget...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("clockWidget","Updating widget...");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have seems fine off the cuff. I'm not sure that you can raise a `Toast` from a `BroadcastReceiver` like that. More importantly, bear in mind that it will only update every half-hour, though, since `android:updatePeriodMillis` will not accept a value lower than a half-hour.

App widgets are not meant to be updated every second. Updating an app widget involves an inter-process communication call, which is not cheap.

Home screen clocks are best implemented by the home screen application, not as app widgets.

Comment: I think that pretty much explains the issue. The Toast and the low update period was just to easily see if it were working or not, but that obviously didn't work... :)

Answer (score 0):

To update a widget more frequently than every half an hour, one can still use android alarm manager.

Something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(<action Name>);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( <you widget class>.this, 0, intent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

And then you can use the Onreceive method of your appwidget provider to deal with the event.